# Classification in R by ID

Tags: r, algorithm, classification, random-forest, prediction

I've been trying to do some classification in R, using the `RandomForestSRC` package, for performance's sake.

In this particular case, I have the following example data.frame, where Y is the classification factor c("X","Y","Z"), ID means that the items are grouped together in the same package, and them I have other variables that will tell me if the result should be X, Y or Z:

```
y    ID    x1    x2    x3    ...

X    01    AA    BB    CC    ...
X    01    AA    BB    DD    ...
X    01    AA    FF    EE    ...
Y    02    AA    BB    CC    ...
Y    02    AA    BB    EE    ...
Z    03    AA    FF    CC    ...
Z    03    AA    FF    EE    ...
...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

After training the algorithm, it successfully gives me the following results, with a great % of accuracy for each individual item, but without grouping the items by package ID:

```
y    ID    x1    x2    x3    ...

Y    01    AA    BB    CC    ...
X    01    AA    BB    DD    ...
Z    01    AA    FF    EE    ...
Y    02    AA    BB    CC    ...
Y    02    AA    BB    EE    ...
Z    03    AA    FF    CC    ...
Z    03    AA    FF    EE    ...
...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

The rules for the package classification should be the following:

1. If at least one of the items is classified as X, the whole package should be X;
2. If there are only Y and Z in the same package, the package should be classified as Y;
3. If there are only Z items in the package, them the whole package should be classified as Z.

Therefore, the weight on the package should be X > Y > Z for classification purpose.

I've tried fiddling with the formulae given to the algorithm, using things like:

```
rf <- rfsrc(y ~ ., data = model, method = "class")
rf <- rfsrc(y ~ ID %in% (x1+x2+x3+...), data = model, method = "class")
rf <- rfsrc(y ~ (x1+x2+x3+...) / ID, data = model, method = "class")
```

However, nothing seems to work really well, and sometimes lowering the accuracy for individual items. I've thought about predicting by layers, using the first result as the model for the second iteration of the algorithm, but I couldn't really find out how to get there.

Should I just give up using random forest for classification, and try some other algorithm altogether? Could maybe `nnet`, or `h2o` work for me? I am rather new to data mining and prediction algorithms altogether, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I guess I found out what I needed.

I've used the `reshape` package to model my data.frame and convert some variables into rows. If anyone else needs it, these are the materials I followed:

http://had.co.nz/reshape/introduction.pdf

https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/01/aggregation-and-restructuring-data-from-r-in-action/

After studying these materials, and some googleing, I came up with the following code:

```
library(reshape)

aux <- melt(myData, id=c('y','ID','x1'))

myData <- as.data.frame(cast(aux, ... ~ variable+value, function(x) { length(x) != 0}))
```

The result was the following reshaped data.frame:

```
y    ID    x1    x2_BB    x2_FF    x3_CC    x3_DD    x3_EE    ...

X    01    AA    TRUE     TRUE    TRUE      TRUE     TRUE     ...
Y    02    AA    TRUE     FALSE   TRUE      FALSE    TRUE     ...
Z    03    AA    FALSE    TRUE    TRUE      FALSE    TRUE     ...
...  ...   ...   ...      ...     ...       ...      ...      ...
```